# How to call javascript function from inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please allow me to ask a silly question about javascript function. I wonder if there's a way to call javascript function from the div. Without giving an id nor class.

**Function**

```
function callTest(){
    name=$(this).attr('data-name');
    clr=$(this).attr('data-clr');

    $(this).html(name+'/'+clr);
}
```

Then I want to print the data from the parent div into its content. By doing something like this.

```
<div data-name="john" data-clr="red">
    <script>callTest()</script>
</div>
```

So I expect this `div` will filled with `john/red`. The reason is there will be a lot of div which is need to pass variable on it's own.

Comment: no way to acces a element without specifing an id. @Wilf

Comment: Can I access it with onload?

Comment: you can acces the function with onload

Comment: but you cannot print to a element without an id @Wilf

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade Of course you can access an element without an id. `document.querySelector('[data-name="john"]')`...

Comment: It should be noted that this `<script>` tag will activate when the page loads, not when the div is clicked or anything. And it won't use the div's scope, either.

Comment: that is accesing it with info about the element or using a query selector. @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: what if i give a div an id an access from function with `$(this).parent('div').html(...)` ???

Comment: Take a look at [dynamic patterns](http://web.archive.org/web/20150820074329/http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript#Changing_the_src_property)

Comment: what are you trying to do first of just to clear this up. @Wilf

Comment: Blocked @RicardoVallejo

Comment: @Wilf When do you want the code to execute?

Comment: when the document is ready `  $(document).ready(function(){...`

Answer (score 3):

It will be better to use `data()` when you want to get data-* attributes :

```
var name = $(this).data('name');
var clr  = $(this).data('clr');
```

Then you could use the attribute selector like `$('div[data-name]')`.
Else it will be better to attach an identifier `id` or a `class` to your element(s).

```js
$('div[data-name]').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var clr = $(this).data('clr');

  $(this).html(name + '/' + clr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-name="john" data-clr="red">
</div>
```

Comment: Do read this though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: How is it better to use data()? The problem that i, personally, have with data() is, that if you change date at runtime, you wont be able to observe it in the elements panel.

Comment: The `data()` method made to set/get the `data-*` attributes, when `attr()` made for all kind of attributes, so it will be better in the specific case that uses `data-*` attributes to use the specific related method.. not sure what you men by _elements panel_ @denns

Comment: In some case `data-*` is not working. So I better specific the full name with `attr`.

Comment: The only time `data()` won't work is if you update an existing value using `attr()`. If you use `data()` as getter and setter (which you should be) then it works fine.

Comment: i meant the chrome dev tools elements panel. every browser has its own variant but its essentially the same... you can see changes to the dom at runtime. @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: @mplungjan link explains in detail what i meant

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this and select all elements with the data-name attribute:

```
$('[data-name]').each(function(){
    let name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    let clr  = $(this).attr('data-clr');
    $(this).html(name+'/'+clr);
});
```

N.B.: Adding a class and using that instead to select the elements is better for performance, as it can use better optimized functions.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$('[data-name]').each(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
  var color =$(this).attr('data-clr');
  $(this).text(name + '/' + color);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This accomplishes what you're trying to do:

```
function callTest() {
  var $div = $('div:last'),
      name = $div.data('name'),
      clr = $div.data('clr');

  document.write(name + '/' + clr);
}
```

As the browser parses through the HTML, the "last" `div` will be the one containing the current script element, even if there are multiple `div`s.

**Example:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function callTest() {
    var $div = $('div:last'),
        name = $div.data('name'),
        clr = $div.data('clr');

    document.write(name + '/' + clr);
  }
</script>

<div data-name="john" data-clr="red">
  <script>callTest()</script>
</div>

<div data-name="mary" data-clr="green">
  <script>callTest()</script>
</div>
```

That is not, however, the best approach.

Instead, change the HTML of all the `div`s like this:

```
$('div[data-name]').html(function() {
  return $(this).data('name') + '/' + $(this).data('clr');
});
```

**Example:**

```js
$('div[data-name]').html(function() {
  return $(this).data('name') + '/' + $(this).data('clr');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-name="john" data-clr="red"></div>

<div data-name="mary" data-clr="green"></div>
```